# signing transaction in web3 is not returning msgHash

Tags: web3js, signature, provable

I am trying to write provble_transfer where owner can pay gas fee for the transaction. Below is the code for signing transaction to my test contact.

```
let rawTransaction = {
        'from': fromAddress,
        'gasPrice': web3js.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        'gasLimit': web3js.utils.toHex(3000000),
        'to': contractAddress,
        'value': "0x0",
        'data': contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, amount).encodeABI(),
        'nonce': web3js.utils.toHex(count),
        "chainId": 4
    };

    let privateKey = Buffer.from(requestPrivateKey, 'hex');
    let transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, {'chain': parameters.ethereum.network});
    transaction.sign(privateKey)
    res.status(constants.HTTP_OK).json({
            data: {
                'transaction_hash': transaction,
                'amount':amount
            },
            status: 'success',
            message: 'Everything went well.'
        });
```

Signed transaction has following data

```
"transaction_hash": {
        "nonce": "0x02b6",
        "gasPrice": "0x04a817c800",
        "gasLimit": "0x2dc6c0",
        "to": "0xdd..,
        "value": "0x",
        "data": "0xa9059cbb00000000000000000000..",
        "v": "0x2c",
        "r": "0x9ee5dddddd",
        "s": "0x50c34909511f1e...."
    }
```

and getSigner function in my contract is

```
function getSigner(
    bytes32[3] data,
    uint8 v
) private returns (address)
{

    address signer = ecrecover(
        keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", data[0]),
        v,
        data[1],
        data[2]
    );

    return signer;
}
```

So question is, getSigner needs an array of three bytes32 values in first param but I have two in above transaction, How can I get msgHash or 1st value for array from the above transaction.

Comment: `I have two in above transaction` - which ones are they?

Comment: r, s are other two, ecrecover needs msgHash, v, r,s. I have everything except msgHash in signed transaction

Comment: What about `data`?

Comment: that is not byte32, that may contain it but I don't know how to extract msghash from it if it contains.

Comment: How about taking its first 66 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first value passed in the array has to be the hash of the signed message.

To verify a signed transaction it is the hash of the transaction without signature

```
txUnsignedHash = transaction.hash(false);
```

For getSigner to work you need some additional fixes:

- v has to be 27 or 28. After [EIP 155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-155) v is `2*chainId + 35` or `2*chainId + 36`. So you will have to adjust to `chainId = 4`

  ```
  newV = v - 43 + 27;
  ```
- Transaction are signed without the prefix `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32"`,

  ```
  ecrecover(data[0],
      v,
      data[1],
      data[2]
  );
  ```

Comment: ok works after fixing the v param. Thanks a lot, you made my day.